# Is it possible to catalog data inside csv files inside Azure Blob Storage using Azure Data Catalog?

Tags: metadata, azure-blob-storage, catalog

I want to catalog data stored in csv files in the Azure Blob Storage. I tried to see if there is anyway to get metadata of Blob Storage and found Data Catalog is an option. Thing is, csv file is handled as a blob type and we can not profile it. I want, csv files in blob storage to act as tables.

Is this possible using Azure Data Catalog?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Data Catalog, For updated Data Catalog features, please use the new Azure Purview service, which offers unified data governance for your entire data estate. I would recommend to use : [Azure Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/overview)( Still you possible through Data Catalog)

Registering assets from a data source copies the assets’ metadata to Azure, but the data remains in the existing data-source location.

For updated Data Catalog features, please use the new Azure Purview service, which offers unified data governance for your entire data estate.
Introduction to Azure Purview (preview) - Azure Purview
This article provides an overview of Azure Purview, including its features and the problems it addresses. Azure Purview enables any user to register, discover, understand, and consume data sources.

[This article outlines how to register an Azure Blob Storage account in Purview and set up a scan.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-azure-blob-storage-source)

- For more information on **Blob index tags** categorize data in your storage account using key-value tag attributes. These tags are automatically indexed and exposed as a searchable multi-dimensional index to easily find data. This article shows you how to set, get, and find data using blob index tags.  [Use blob index tags to manage and find data on Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-index-how-to?tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: Other than this option, is there no other way we can get catalog of data inside all CSV files and run queries on the data using the obtained catalog information? In AWS for example, S3 can store different CSV files, we use GLUE and Athena services to get the catalog of the CSV files and query data from obtained catalog information.
In Azure is there no way to use already existing services to read data in CSV files without downloading them in local environment? The solution you have mentioned is a custom solution

Comment: Azure purview does not solve my problem, i need data inside csv to be profiled.